# Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid when using where inside include

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

```
  User user = await _context.users
.Include(u => u.orders.Where(o => o.Date > startDate && o.Date < enddate))
.Where(u => u.UserID == _auth.User.UserID)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

So I have one-to-many relationships between the Users and Orders table, where the user model has a List orders. But I get a 500 server error and "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid"

Comment: `Include` is for eagerly loading all related data, you cannot use any type of LINQ query. If you need to filter data, you need to get it in a second query

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by downloading EF plus, and changing the query to

```
User user = await _context.users.IncludeFilter(u => u.orders.Where(o => o.Date > startDate && o.Date < enddate)).Where(u => u.UserID == _auth.User.UserID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```